# Capturing Sybase Showplan programmatically

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy in python to execute  my sql queries. I have prefixed my sql queries with a show plan on. However I am not getting the plan back from my results. Does anyone know if the results for the plan is stored somewhere in some system table or is there some flag that needs to be enabled for sqlalchemy DB API to capture the plan?

Just to re-iterate I'm running against a sybase database

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth trying

```
set noexec on
```

... as well to see if a query plan comes back.